# Could not load content for https://x.com/wp-content/.../assets/css/bootstrap.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress website and I'm getting this error:

*DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://aurachain.ch/wp-content/themes/leadengineLead/core/assets/css/bootstrap.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE*

On the front-end of the website i believe this error is causing some font awesome icons not to load - [see on this page for example that the "fa fa-play" icon that is not loading.](https://aurachain.ch/about-us/)

I've seen a couple of answers to a similar problem where it says that you need to go to Developer Tools in your developer console settings and fix it there but I have it already checked and the error is still showing...so I think the problem is somewhere else. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the front-end error on the website I was seeing on font awesome icons not loading was actually caused by a plugin Redux by Extendify and was fixed through a rollback of its version.

The warning *DevTools failed to load source map* showing in the dev console is still showing. Is it something to worry about?

Comment: While its valid to answer your own question on Stackoverflow this answer doesn't seem to resolve your question, so I'd move this to a comment on your question so others will be more likely to answer.